# Not receiving any notifications in elementary OS 6

Tags: notifications

This was working yesterday when I installed,though I've done a bit of setup afterwards and now can't figure out why I'm not receiving notifications anymore.  Even just running `notify-send "Hello world!"` in the terminal doesn't prompt anything.  Any idea how I can troubleshoot?

Comment: Do you see any error messages in `/var/log/syslog` that might point to why the notification is not being seen?

Comment: I think that `notify-send` is disabled by default and apps should use [a different API](https://docs.elementary.io/develop/apis/notifications) for notifications. Running `notify-send` also doesn't do anything for me, although I recieve notifications from apps correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with this. I'm having notifications normally in the beggining but I don't know why days later I don't have more notifications from the panel, like volume up/down, bluetooth and the usual notifications.

In the configuration settings all notifications are activated and looks normal but doesn't show.

Some advice to restart this, please?

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue seemed to be caused by the "Deepin Screenshot" plugin. After uninstalling the utility, the OS notifications returned properly.

You can remove Deepin Screenshot from the software center, or from the Terminal with:

```
sudo apt remove deepin-screenshot
```

You can then test it with:

```
notify-send "Hello world!"
```